# How to render a component after setState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this is a common question, but after hours of searching for an answer, I decided to ask for help.

I'm trying to pass a state variable to a component, but the component was rendered before the value was set

my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Seguradora from "../../components/seguradora/seguradora.component";

const CorretorasShow = () => {
  const obj = useLocation();
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url =
      "http://localhost:3001/corretoras/63338f415c502044e953d408" +
      obj.state._id;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        setNames(json.seguradora); // <<<<<< setState
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Seguradora props={names} /> //<<<<< state varible
    </div>
  );
};
```

I've tried useMemo, useRef and ternary operator to no avail.
I'm not an expert programmer and I'm new to reactJS so I may have done something wrong with these workarounds

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the type of `names` ? array or string?

Comment: Oh, `names > 0` will always be true, you want `names.length > 0`

Comment: my question can be: how to set the variable value before rendering the component.
Right now what happens is that the component is rendered and variable that i'm passing to it is null. 
names is a array of objects.

Comment: `names` isn't null on first render because you initialize it to an empty array `[]` which ISN'T null. Why do you think it's null? And are you sure `json.seguradora` has data in it? Get in the habit of using console.log to verify your data is what you expect, and get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since fetching data is async action, fetched data, in this case `names`, will be undefined at the moment of rendering child component. To avoid that, you need to check if `names` array has values and render child component only if that's true.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Seguradora from "../../components/seguradora/seguradora.component";

const CorretorasShow = () => {
  const obj = useLocation();
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url =
      "http://localhost:3001/corretoras/63338f415c502044e953d408" +
      obj.state._id;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        setNames(json.seguradora); // <<<<<< setState
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      { names.length !== 0 && <Seguradora props={names} /> }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. It's unbelievable that I couldn't find such a simple solution.

All I found were methods using useMemo, reducers or workarounds that didn't solve my case.
This should be upvoted on so other people can see it as it is a common situation with react

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. `names` shouldn't be a dependency of the `useEffect`. The `useEffect` should have `[]` in the dependency array like in the original question, so that it fires only once, when the component loads. Adding an API response to the dependency of an API call doesn't make sense because the API call doesn't depend on the response. You've only confused @IgorFerreira, please delete this answer.

Comment: @AndyRay I agree, but I can't delete the answer since it's accepted, so I'll edit it

Comment: @AndyRay Do you have any suggestion on how solve the issue then? 

The original answer from Jovana worked for me. but I agree that I got a bit confused as I'm new to react and I don't find useEffect easy to understand

Comment: @IgorFerreira I've updated my answer, it should be fine now

Comment: @IgorFerreira my comment answers your question, so does Caio's other answer. @Jovana this is still wrong because you forgot `{}`. Igor, if the originally answer made it work, then you're doing something else wrong, and might be ignoring errors in the console. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions. Your original question shows misunderstanding of your own problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since `names` is an Array, you can check if the Array is populated to conditionally render your component, like this:

```
return (
    <div>
      { names.length > 0 ?  <Seguradora props={names} /> : null} 
    </div>
  );
```